# Visual Basic date program

Tags: vb.net, date

So I made a Batch file earlier today which would only work on the Christmas day
and I was wondering if there is a way to recreate this in **Visual Basic.**

Here is the code for the **batch** file. Maybe you can help me to recreate this in Visual Basic

```
    @echo off
    echo %date%|find " 25/12/2013" >nul 
     if not errorlevel 1 (
       echo MERRY CHRISTMAS!
     ) else (
       goto blocked
     )
    :blocked
    exit
```

**So the question is:** How can I recreate this in **Visual Basic** (You don't need to tell how can I add the "MERRY CHRISTMAS" text, I only need to know how to make it only work on a specific date.)

And by the way, **Task Scheluder** is not a option, I'm making this for my friends too

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test you want in your code looks like this:

```
if Date.Today = #12/25/2013# then
    ' Do Something
end if
```

I'll leave the rest up to you.